# Getting UserIdentity returns the old identity

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

In MVC I have custom AuthorizeAttribute. So inside this attribute I sign in UserIdentity with cookie authentication. In my claims I have refresh token which is changed in each request to the API as you know.

```
request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(AuthProperties, identity);
```

So after login I'm signed in with specific refresh token claim(For example 'xxxxx'). I access one of my Actions that has CustomAuthorizeAttribute. In the CustomAuthorizeAttribute the above code is executed. So I'm signed in with new identity and new refresh token claim("yyyyyy"). But when I try to get the claim in the Action the refresh token is the old one ("xxxxxx").

```
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public ActionResult EditUser()
    {
        var userIdentity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        //here is the old one token
        var refreshToken = userIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Type == "RefreshToken").Value; 

        return View("EditUser");
    }
```

Any ideas how to get the latest token from the claims. Other workaround is to save it in session I guess.

Comment: you're using `.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Type == "RefreshToken")`. How many "Claims" of that type there are? Try with `.Count(s => s.Type == "RefreshToken")` to look if there's also the new one.

Comment: I checked. It's just one RefreshToken

Comment: OK. I'd suggest posting the code following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)